# Mobile device as database server

Tags: android, ios, database, html, networking

Is it possible for one mobile device to act as database server for another devices (clients) in the same network. I know there are lot of embedded mobile database like sqllite, couchdb lite, pouch db etc but they are meant to sync with remote server and work as standalone database for a single mobile device. I want to make very lite hybrid offline mobile app which should work without internet but should have facility to share data between two or more device in the same wifi network.

Comment: What a thought (y)!! I don't think so there is any open source who has developed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered multipeer connectivity API? http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I have alternative things.

1. Use Cloud service like Dropbox, Google Drive, And Box.
2. Make server app that can communication with client app, and you can share your data.